# How to mock Google Analytics function call ga()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, google-analytics, jasmine, google-analytics-api

I have a service *MyService* with a function using the `ga()` event tracking call which I want to test:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('MyService', [function() {

    var myFunc = function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'bla');
        // do some stuff
    }

    return {
        myFunc: myFunc
    }
]);
```

My spec file looks like this:

```
describe('The MyService', function () {

    var MyService,
        ga;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myModule');
        ga = function() {};
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (_MyService_) {
        MyService = _MyService_;
    }));

    it('should do some stuff', function () {
        MyService.myFunc();
        // testing function
    });
});
```

Running my tests always gives me:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ga

Comment: If you want to test a service, you should not be using Protractor. Protractor is designed for developing and running *end-to-end tests*, testing your application as a whole from a user's perspective in a browser.

Comment: sorry, I am, of course, talking about unit testing - changed my text

Comment: ga is defined inside the function, is not global. Try with window.ga = function() {}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is global scope of `ga`.

The `ga` variable that you create inside your tests has a local scope and will not be visible to your own service.

By using a global variable (`ga`) you have made unit testing difficult.

The current option would be to either create a angular service to wrap `ga`and use that everywhere else. Such service can be mocked too.

The other option is to override the global `ga`. But this will have side effects.

`window.ga=function() {}`

Comment: thanks, is there a way to spy or intercept somehow on a global var?

Comment: You can try  `spyOn(window, 'ga');`

Comment: Same for dataLayer`window.dataLayer = {
      push: function() {}
    }`

Comment: see also: [stackoverflow.com / mocking-globals-in-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest)

Answer (score 5):

After trying different solution I finally fixed with below code.

```
beforeAll( ()=> {
    // (<any>window).gtag=function() {} // if using gtag
    (<any>window).ga=function() {}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly out of date, but I am trying to leverage ReactGA and mocked creating an event like:

```
it('should do something...', () => {
    const gaSpy = jest.spyOn(ReactGA, 'ga');
    someService.functionThatSendsEvent({ ...necessaryParams });
    expect(gaSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('send', 'event',
       expect.objectContaining({/*whatever the event object is supposed to be*/}
    );
});
```

This is helpful if youre sending specific data to an angular/reactjs service which is then sending it to GA.

Comment: I am not using ReactGA but want to test my /collect calls with GA4. what should use for it?