# Mocking globals in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dependencies, jestjs, babel-jest

Is there any way in Jest to mock global objects, such as `navigator`, or `Image`*? I've pretty much given up on this, and left it up to a series of mockable utility methods. For example:

```
// Utils.js
export isOnline() {
    return navigator.onLine;
}
```

Testing this tiny function is simple, but crufty and not deterministic at all. I can get 75% of the way there, but this is about as far as I can go:

```
// Utils.test.js
it('knows if it is online', () => {
    const { isOnline } = require('path/to/Utils');

    expect(() => isOnline()).not.toThrow();
    expect(typeof isOnline()).toBe('boolean');
});
```

On the other hand, if I am okay with this indirection, I can now access `navigator` via these utilities:

```
// Foo.js
import { isOnline } from './Utils';

export default class Foo {
    doSomethingOnline() {
        if (!isOnline()) throw new Error('Not online');

        /* More implementation */            
    }
}
```

...and deterministically test like this...

```
// Foo.test.js
it('throws when offline', () => {
    const Utils = require('../services/Utils');
    Utils.isOnline = jest.fn(() => isOnline);

    const Foo = require('../path/to/Foo').default;
    let foo = new Foo();

    // User is offline -- should fail
    let isOnline = false;
    expect(() => foo.doSomethingOnline()).toThrow();

    // User is online -- should be okay
    isOnline = true;
    expect(() => foo.doSomethingOnline()).not.toThrow();
});
```

Out of all the testing frameworks I've used, Jest feels like the most complete solution, but any time I write awkward code just to make it testable, I feel like my testing tools are letting me down.

Is this the only solution or do I need to add Rewire?

*Don't smirk. `Image` is fantastic for pinging a remote network resource.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-can-i-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest

Answer (score 135, accepted):

As every **test suite** run its own environment, you can mock globals by just overwriting them. All global variables can be accessed by the `global` namespace:

```
global.navigator = {
  onLine: true
}
```

The overwrite has only effects in your current test and will not effect others. This also a good way to handle `Math.random` or `Date.now`.

Note, that through some changes in [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) it could be possible that you have to mock globals like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(globalObject, key, { value, writable: true });
```

Comment: Will `global` be the same as `window` in the browser?

Comment: Yes in the the sense that you can set the stuff there. But maybe not all the stuff that is present in `window` is also present in `global`. Thats why I don't use `global.navigator.onLine` cause I'm not sure that there is a `navigator` object in `global`.

Comment: Be aware that as a general practice not all global properties are overwritable nowadays. Some have writable false and will ignore value change attempts.

Comment: "The overwrite has only effects in your current test and will not effect others." - is that documented anywhere?

Comment: Great! I had to mock `performance`, which I'd never seen before, so I did: `global.performance = { now: () => {} };`

Comment: @JamesPlayer I can definitely confirm, that an overwrite in one test **will** effect the other tests. At least in one test suite.

Comment: @JoCa Thank for mentioning it. I've updated the answer to be more precise.

Comment: defineProperty worked but for the property I needed, it I had to do it this way.

    `Object.defineProperty(global, 'external', { writable: true });
    global.external = {
      JSFunctionReady: JSFunctionReadyMock,
    };`

Both in one call did not work.

Answer (score 43):

The correct way of doing this is to use [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname). The other answers here, even though they work, don't consider cleanup and pollute the global scope.

```js
// beforeAll
jest
  .spyOn(window, 'navigator', 'get')
  .mockImplementation(() => { ... })

// afterAll
jest.restoreAllMocks();
```

Comment: This gave me "Property navigator does not have access type get" - which version of Jest is this supposed work?

Comment: Try: 
`jest.spyOn('window.navigator', 'get')`

Answer (score 23):

Jest may have changed since the accepted answer was written, but Jest does not appear to reset your global after testing. Please see the testcases attached.

https://repl.it/repls/DecentPlushDeals

As far as I know, the only way around this is with an `afterEach()` or `afterAll()` to clean up your assignments to `global`.

```
let originalGlobal = global;
afterEach(() => {
  delete global.x;
})

describe('Scope 1', () => {
  it('should assign globals locally', () => {
    global.x = "tomato";
    expect(global.x).toBeTruthy()
  });  
});

describe('Scope 2', () => {
  it('should not remember globals in subsequent test cases', () => {
    expect(global.x).toBeFalsy();
  })
});
```

Comment: I experienced the same behaviour, that my global variable was not reset after each test run. Calling `jest.clearAllMocks();` in `afterEach()` helped me

Comment: in Angular ... import { global } from '@angular/compiler/src/util'

Comment: Since tests can run in parallel, even calling `jest.clearAllMocks()` in `afterEach()` may fail.

Comment: Is `global` reset after whole `describe` block has finished running? Whole test suite? Or like never?

Answer (score 10):

If someone needs to mock a **global** with **static properties** then my example should help:

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    global.EventSource = jest.fn(() => ({
      readyState: 0,
      close: jest.fn()
    }))

    global.EventSource.CONNECTING = 0
    global.EventSource.OPEN = 1
    global.EventSource.CLOSED = 2
  })
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `react-testing-library` and you use the `cleanup` method provided by the library, it will remove all global declarations made in that file once all tests in the file have run. This will then not carry over to any other tests run.

Example:

```
import { cleanup } from 'react-testing-library'

afterEach(cleanup)

global.getSelection = () => {

}

describe('test', () => {
  expect(true).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Comment: I believe this is the default behavior as of `@testing-library/react` v9.0, and the `cleanup-after-each` functionality was removed in v10.0 -- https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases

Comment: You says "once all tests in the file have run" but you use `afterEach`, which is contradictory

Answer (score 2):

If you need to assign *and* reassign the value of a property on `window.navigator` then you'll need to:

1. Declare a non-constant variable
2. Return it from the global/window object
3. Change the value of that original variable (by reference)

This will prevent errors when trying to reassign the value on `window.navigator` because these are mostly read-only.

```
let mockUserAgent = "";

beforeAll(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, "userAgent", {
    get() {
      return mockUserAgent;
    },
  });
});

it("returns the newly set attribute", () => {
  mockUserAgent = "secret-agent";
  expect(window.navigator.userAgent).toEqual("secret-agent");
});
```