# How can I mock the JavaScript 'window' object using Jest?

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I need to test a function which opens a new tab in the browser

```
openStatementsReport(contactIds) {
  window.open(`a_url_${contactIds}`);
}
```

I would like to mock *window*'s `open` function, so I can verify the correct URL is passed in to the `open` function.

Using Jest, I don't know how to mock `window`. I tried to set `window.open` with a mock function, but this way doesn't work. Below is the test case:

```
it('the correct URL is called', () => {
  window.open = jest.fn();
  statementService.openStatementsReport(111);
  expect(window.open).toBeCalled();
});
```

But it gives me the error

```
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toBeCalled()

jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function anonymous]
```

What should I do to the test case?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274889/jest-test-fails-with-window-is-not-defined/50376346#comment133217121_50376346

Answer (score 220):

The following method worked for me. This approach allowed me to test some code that should work both in the browser and in Node.js, as it allowed me to set `window` to `undefined`.

This was with Jest 24.8 (I believe):

```
let windowSpy;

beforeEach(() => {
  windowSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "window", "get");
});

afterEach(() => {
  windowSpy.mockRestore();
});

it('should return https://example.com', () => {
  windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
    location: {
      origin: "https://example.com"
    }
  }));

  expect(window.location.origin).toEqual("https://example.com");
});

it('should be undefined.', () => {
  windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => undefined);

  expect(window).toBeUndefined();
});
```

Comment: That's much better than `Object.defineProperty` since this allows not to affect other tests when mocking.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it mocks/spies instead of changing the actual global property

Comment: I just used `x = jest.spyOn(window, 'open')` and `x.mockImplementation(() => {})`, fyi, but all i needed to mock was window.open.

Comment: @temporary_user_name I was looking for a way to mock window.open and you saved my day, thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the `The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.` error.

Comment: Unfortunately not a compatible approach with typescript.

Comment: @BrianC You can cast the correct type. In this case 

`windowSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "window", "get") as jest.Mock;`

Answer (score 135):

Instead of `window`, use `global`:

```
it('the correct URL is called', () => {
  global.open = jest.fn();
  statementService.openStatementsReport(111);
  expect(global.open).toBeCalled();
});
```

You could also try:

```
const open = jest.fn()
Object.defineProperty(window, 'open', open);
```

Comment: These approaches throw errors these days, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999581 still works.

Answer (score 39):

There are a couple of ways to mock globals in Jest:

1. Use the `mockImplementation` approach (the most Jest-like way), but it will work only for those variables which has some default implementation provided by `jsdom`. `window.open` is one of them:

   ```js
   test('it works', () => {
     // Setup
     const mockedOpen = jest.fn();
     // Without making a copy, you will have a circular dependency problem
     const originalWindow = { ...window };
     const windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, "window", "get");
     windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
       ...originalWindow, // In case you need other window properties to be in place
       open: mockedOpen
     }));

     // Tests
     statementService.openStatementsReport(111)
     expect(mockedOpen).toBeCalled();

     // Cleanup
     windowSpy.mockRestore();
   });
   ```
2. Assign the value directly to the global property. It is the most straightforward, but it may trigger error messages for some `window` variables, e.g. `window.href`.

   ```js
   test('it works', () => {
     // Setup
     const mockedOpen = jest.fn();
     const originalOpen = window.open;
     window.open = mockedOpen;

     // Tests
     statementService.openStatementsReport(111)
     expect(mockedOpen).toBeCalled();

     // Cleanup
     window.open = originalOpen;
   });
   ```
3. Don't use globals directly (requires a bit of refactoring)

   Instead of using the global value directly, it might be cleaner to import it from another file, so mocking will became trivial with Jest.

#### File *./test.js*

```js
jest.mock('./fileWithGlobalValueExported.js');
import { windowOpen } from './fileWithGlobalValueExported.js';
import { statementService } from './testedFile.js';

// Tests
test('it works', () => {
  statementService.openStatementsReport(111)
  expect(windowOpen).toBeCalled();
});
```

#### File *./fileWithGlobalValueExported.js*

```js
export const windowOpen = window.open;
```

#### File *./testedFile.js*

```js
import { windowOpen } from './fileWithGlobalValueExported.js';
export const statementService = {
  openStatementsReport(contactIds) {
    windowOpen(`a_url_${contactIds}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

I'm directly assigning `jest.fn()` to `window.open`.

```js
window.open = jest.fn()
// ...code
expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/new-tab','_blank')
```

Answer (score 19):

In my component I need access to `window.location.search`. This is what I did in the Jest test:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, "window", {
  value: {
    location: {
      search: "test"
    }
  }
});
```

In case window properties must be different in different tests, we can put window mocking into a function, and make it writable in order to override for different tests:

```
function mockWindow(search, pathname) {
  Object.defineProperty(global, "window", {
    value: {
      location: {
        search,
        pathname
      }
    },
    writable: true
  });
}
```

And reset after each test:

```
afterEach(() => {
  delete global.window.location;
});
```

Answer (score 14):

We can also define it using `global` in `setupTests`:

```
// File 'setupTests.js'
global.open = jest.fn()
```

And call it using `global` in the actual test:

```
// File 'yourtest.test.js'
it('the correct URL is called', () => {
    statementService.openStatementsReport(111);
    expect(global.open).toBeCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I found an easy way to do it: delete and replace

```js
describe('Test case', () => {
  const { open } = window;

  beforeAll(() => {
    // Delete the existing
    delete window.open;
    // Replace with the custom value
    window.open = jest.fn();
    // Works for `location` too, eg:
    // window.location = { origin: 'http://localhost:3100' };
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    // Restore original
    window.open = open;
  });

  it('correct url is called', () => {
    statementService.openStatementsReport(111);
    expect(window.open).toBeCalled(); // Happy happy, joy joy
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

### The `window` object in Jest is self-mocking

One of the things unaddressed in other answers is a comment by the OP:

> Using Jest, I don't know how to mock the `window`.

The `window` object is **already mocked** and can be referenced out of the box.

From [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-jquery):

> Jest ships with jsdom which simulates a DOM environment as if you were in the browser. This means that every DOM API that we call can be observed in the same way it would be observed in a browser!

##### Example:

```
describe('i am a window', () => {
    it('has a window object', () => {
      expect(window).toBeTruthy(); // test will pass
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
import * as _Window from "jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window";

window.open = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return new _Window({ parsingMode: "html" });
});

it("correct url is called", () => {
    statementService.openStatementsReport(111);
    expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If it's similar to the window location problem at *[window.location.href can't be changed in tests. #890](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/890)*, you could try (adjusted):

```
delete global.window.open;
global.window = Object.create(window);
global.window.open = jest.fn();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try simply:

```
let windowOpenSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
beforeEach(() => {
    windowOpenSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'open');
});

it('should open window with dashboard url', () => {
    expect(windowOpenSpy).toBeCalledWith('your URL', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: this is how I imagined the answer looking, and I can say this approach worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your Jest configuration, add setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./setupTests.js"], create that file, and add the code you want to run before the tests:

```
// setupTests.js
window.crypto = {
   .....
};
```

Reference: *[setupFilesAfterEnv [array]](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array)*

Answer (score 1):

You can test it:

```
describe('TableItem Components', () => {
    let open_url = ""
    const { open } = window;
    beforeAll(() => {
        delete window.open;
        window.open = (url) => { open_url = url };
    });
    afterAll(() => {
        window.open = open;
    });
    test('string type', async () => {
        wrapper.vm.openNewTab('http://example.com')
        expect(open_url).toBe('http://example.com')
    })
})
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

I have a utility function which allows me to mock any method on the window like so:

```
  function givenMockWindowMethods(methods: Partial<{ [key in keyof Window]: jest.Mock<any, any> }>): () => void {
    const mocks = Object.values(methods);

    Object.entries(methods).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      Object.defineProperty(window, key, { value });
    });

    return (): void => mocks.forEach((mock) => mock?.mockClear());
  }
```

So if I need to mock the `open` method (or anything really) on the window, I can do:

```
      const cleanupMocks = givenMockWindowMethods({ open: jest.fn() });
      // expect(...).toBe(...)

      //at the end of the test, clean it up
      cleanupMocks()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const windowSpy = jest.spyOn(iFrame, "contentWindow", "get");
windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
  location: {
    origin: "https://test.com",
    href: "href",
    hash: "hash"
  }
}));
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar test, and it worked with me...

My code:

```
export const Blah = () => {
        const BLAH = 'https://www.google.com/'
        const handleBlah = () => {
            window.open(BLAH, '_blank')
        }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleBlah}> BLAHBLAH </button>
    )
}
```

My test using Jest:

```
it('should be able to render "BLAHBLAH " button ', () => {
    window.open = jest.fn();
    const BLAH = 'https://www.google.com/'
    const { getByText } = render(<Blah/>) // Get text by my page Blah
    const buttonGoToBlah = getByText('BLAHBLAH') // Get button by text
    fireEvent.click(buttonGoToBlah) // Simulate the click event

    expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // Expect the window.open have to been called at least once.
    expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(BLAH, '_blank'); // And the page should be the same called in my BLAH page
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Date: July 2023**

**Jest version: 28.1.3**

This version spys on window.open (via global.open) then restores window.open after all tests are completed.

```
const realOpen = global.open; // store real window.open

describe('Given [thing you are testing]', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global, 'open'); // create spy in beforeAll hook
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    global.open = realOpen; // after all the tests are completed restore window.open in afterAll hook
  });

  it('the correct URL is called', () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks(); // clear all mocks before running statementService.openStatementsReport
    statementService.openStatementsReport(111);
    expect(global.open).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```