# Test case to check if Button onClick opens a new tab

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sinon, chai, karma-mocha

I am new to UI development and recently I have started to write code in React using Typescript. 
I have created a Button and after clicking the same, it opens a menu with some options to select from. If I click on one of the option a new tab will be opened with some target URL. I am using 
`window.open(target_URL, "_blank");`
to achieve this.

Now I am writing test cases for my code and I want to write a test case that checks if I click on that option it opens a new tab with the target_URL.

```
const myButton: HTMLElement = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(renderedComponent, "my-button") as HTMLElement;
    expect(myButton).to.not.be.undefined;

    // Click the Button and check number of options displayed
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(myButton);
    const menuItems: HTMLElement[] = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(renderedComponent, "ms-ContextualMenu-item") as HTMLElement[];
    expect(menuItems).to.not.be.undefined;
    expect(menuItems.length).to.be.equal(4, "4 options dispalyed");

    const menuItem1: HTMLElement = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(renderedComponent, "menu-item-1") as HTMLElement;
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(menuItem1);
```

I have written the above code but I am not sure how to complete this to check the case of opening a new tab in the browser.

Comment: This other thread helped me; hope it will do the same for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999581/14814467

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` method will return the window object, you can check that widow:
for example, just try to close the window.

Normally, you can only close the window that you created, otherwise, there would be an error occur.

Comment: Isn't testing implementation details discouraged?