# Jest URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, blob, jestjs

I'm developping a reactJs application. I'm using jest to test my application.
I want to test a function that download a blob.

But unfortunately I receve this error:

> URL.createObjectURL is not a function

my test function:

```
describe('download', () => {
    const documentIntial = { content: 'aaa' };
    it('msSaveOrOpenBlob should not have been called when navigao is undefined', () => {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob = null;
      download(documentIntial);
      expect(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    });
  });
```

The function I want to test:

```
export const download = document => {
  const blob = new Blob([base64ToArrayBuffer(document.content)], {
    type: 'application/pdf',
  });
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
    return;
  }

  const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(fileURL);
};
```

Comment: Now reading a bit about **your** jest, it even seems your question is a [tag:jsdom] one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock the JavaScript window object using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-to-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This would appear to be as simple as setting up `URL` on the Global in Jest.  Something like

```js
describe('download', () => {
  const documentIntial = { content: 'aaa' };
  global.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
  it('msSaveOrOpenBlob should not have been called when navigao is undefined', () => {
    global.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn(() => 'details');
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob = jest.fn(() => 'details');
    download(documentIntial);
    expect(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

This should result in a test that you can also use for checking if `global.URL.createObjectURL` was called.  As a side note: you may also run into a similar issue with `window.open` I would suggest mocking that as well if this becomes the case.

Comment: I have this result :  expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledTimes()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received: undefined

Comment: Take a look at that I actually tested it this time.  You should not be nulling the msSaveOrOpenBlob.  You will want to mock it to be able to tell how often it has been called... otherwise it is not going to give you a call count.

Answer (score 34):

Since `window.URL.createObjectURL` is not (yet) available in jest-dom, you need to provide a mock implementation for it.

Don't forget to reset the mock implementation after each test.

```
describe("your test suite", () => {
  window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();

  afterEach(() => {
    window.URL.createObjectURL.mockReset();
  });

  it("your test case", () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 19):

jsdom, the JavaScript implementation of the WHATWG DOM used by jest doesn't implement this method yet.

You can find an [open ticket about this exact issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1721) on their [github page](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) where some workarounds are provided in comments. But if you need the blobURL to actually work you'll have to wait this FR is solved.

Workaround proposed in the comments of the issue for jest:

```
function noOp () { }
if (typeof window.URL.createObjectURL === 'undefined') { 
  Object.defineProperty(window.URL, 'createObjectURL', { value: noOp})
}
```

Answer (score 19):

> You just have to Write this in your setupTest.js

```
window.URL.createObjectURL = function() {};
```

Comment: This finally worked for me when several other options didn't.

Answer (score 8):

Just mocking the function `global.URL.createObjectURL` did not work for me, because the function was used by some modules during import and I got the error *Jest URL.createObjectURL is not a function* during import.

Instead it did help to create a file `mockJsdom.js`

```
Object.defineProperty(URL, 'createObjectURL', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn()
})
```

Then import this file as the first import in your file containing the test

```
import './mockJsdom'
import { MyObjects} from '../../src/lib/mylib'

test('my test', () => {
  // test code
}
```

Found here: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom

Comment: I wrote the mock function just before starting of the test suite. That too worked. Thanks a lot for this useful answer and reference link as well.

Comment: Also add "import {jest} from '@jest/globals';" at the top of mockJsdom file. From : https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

Answer (score 7):

The package [jsdom-worker](https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker) happens to provide this method, as well as adding support for web workers. The following worked for me:

```
npm install -D jsdom-worker
```

Then in package.json, edit or add a `jest` key:

```
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "jsdom-worker"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of the box, Create React App does not support overriding the Jest option "setupFiles".

Comment: @Hultan but you can create an isolate jest.config.js file, which is better to isolate functionality

Answer (score 0):

Using react-testing-library with jest:

I had to add `jest.spyOn(URL, 'createObjectURL').mockImplementation();` inside my test.
This worked in conjunction with creating a mock file for the dom object

```
Object.defineProperty(URL, 'createObjectURL', {writable: true, value: jest.fn()})
```

and adding the import statement for that mock file as the first import inside my testing file.

*Note*: the mock file cannot be inside the **tests** directory

Answer (score 0):

this code simulates a blob url to test your full cycle

```
    global.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn(
      (blob: any) => `blob:${blob.size}#t=${Date.now()}`
    )
```