# Openlayers 6 TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: jestjs, openlayers-6, mocha-webpack, createobjecturl

I have a question, after i update the openlayers from 5.3.1 to 6.3.1, when i run test, jest or mocha, both show the error "TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function", what is the reason?

Mocha-Webpack:

```
TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/ol/worker/webgl.js?:7:15)
```

Jest:

FAIL test/map.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function

> 1 | import {Vector as VectorLayer} from "ol/layer.js";
    | ^
```

Comment: OpenLayers 6 uses WebGL for Heatmap layers and includes a plugin for webgl workers which uses URL.createObjectURL
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/tasks/serialize-workers.js#L46  To use a Heatmap layer you will need to enable URL in Jest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968969/jest-url-createobjecturl-is-not-a-function

Comment: Thanks for your answer!