# typescript-eslint/unbound-method when mocking window.URL.createObjectURL

Tags: typescript, jestjs, eslint

I am trying to get my unit test working. It currently fails with:

```
TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function
```

I eventually stumble upon:

- [Jest URL.createObjectURL is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968969/jest-url-createobjecturl-is-not-a-function)

So I am now providing the following mock:

```
  test('my test', async (): Promise<void> => {
    window.URL.createObjectURL = (object: any): string => object.toString();
```

However this makes eslint reports now:

```
Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`.
```

Even after reading twice:

- https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v2.24.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/unbound-method.md

It feels like `(object: any): string => object.toString()` is correct here. What am I missing / misunderstanding ?