# jest create-react-app node env window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I using create-react-app with redux and log4javascript. I have started writing integration tests and running `npm run test` with `--env=node`. After I started using `node`, I am getting `window is not defined` error.

Is there a way to define `window` as global object while running jest tests? I have tried setting

```
global.window = jest.fn(() => {
  location: { search: '' }
})
```

but still not working.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-to-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `--env=node`?  The default test environment for `Jest` is `jsdom` which provides a browser environment including the `window` object.  The `node` environment is for apps designed to run on `node` (server code, etc.).  It sounds like you are testing a React app, that should be tested in the `jsdom` environment.

Comment: I actually have little confusion on that as well. I think `jsdom` is the way to go. But facing some other issues related to my app.