# Jest error when setting or assigning 'window.location'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, window, location-href

I upgraded the Jest library to v25 and all unit tests that were checking *location* change are failing.

I checked [a couple of issues opened on the Jest repository](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5124), but I didn't actually understand how can this be fixed.

The code that calls `location.assign` breaks with the following error:

```
Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)

      69 |     // window.location.href = url;
    > 70 |     window.location.assign(url);
```

I suppose that the Jest jsdom *window* object shouldn't be treated any more like a real browser window with regards to changing the location.

How can I fix this?

---

**My findings:**

- Navigation in the tests doesn't work. All these methods that work in the browser are not implemented in the JSDom window:

  - `window.location.href = "https://myapp.com"`
  - `window.location.assign("https://myapp.com")`
  - `window.location.replace("https://myapp.com")`
  - `Object.defineProperty(window.location, "href", { writable: true, value: currentUrl }); window.location has been set as` [Unforgeable](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#Unforgeable)

To fix failing tests I used:

1. `window.history.pushState({}, "title", "/testJest");`
2. `delete window.location; window.location = { assign: jest.fn() };`

   `it("should navigate to the new URL", () => { const myUrl = "http://some.url"; expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith(myUrl); });`

Comment: Your point "2." was just what I needed to fix my test. Thank you.

Comment: pushState solved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it short, "global" is "window" in Jest.

Use:

```
global.location.assign(url);
```

I believe that you can find the rest of the answer in *[How can I mock the JavaScript window object using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-to-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest)*.

Also, there is an interesting conversation around this on this issue:

[*I found* ***window*** *is* ***global*** *in Jest from Stack Overflow, but not mentioned in documentation #3692*](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3692)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is accepted, as I ma getting same error using `global` :/

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following code in your test file.

```
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    writable: true,
    value: { assign: jest.fn() }
  });
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70968655/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

```js
    window.history.replaceState({}, "", decodeURIComponent(url));
```

happy coding :)

Comment: How is that related to *window.location*? Are you sure it is not accidental? Can you elaborate?

Comment: It changes window.location automatically just try it yourself in console here... I copy pasted this url and added `q` param into it instead of url variable in snippet
`window.history.replaceState({}, "", decodeURIComponent('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954101/jest-error-when-setting-or-assigning-window-location/72365703?noredirect=1#comment129349849_72365703?q=dasdasdas'));` voila, works without refresh :)

Comment: For double check you can even call `window.location + ''` in console afterwards to see that it returns changed windo.location url ;)