# How to mock document.location.href in react jest unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I have a simple redux action creator that sets the `document.location.href = "/signin"`

My action creator looks like this

```
export const signout = () => (dispatch) => {
    localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
    localStorage.removeItem("cartItems");
    localStorage.removeItem("shippingAddress");
    dispatch({ type: USER_SIGNOUT });
    document.location.href = "/signin";
};
```

When I run my unit test for the signout action creator I'm seeing the following error:

> ```
> console.error
>   Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)
>       at module.exports (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
>       at navigateFetch (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/navigation.js:76:3)
>       at exports.navigate (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/navigation.js:54:3)
>       at LocationImpl._locationObjectNavigate (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/Location-impl.js:31:5)
>       at LocationImpl._locationObjectSetterNavigate (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/Location-impl.js:25:17)
>       at LocationImpl.set href [as href] (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/Location-impl.js:47:10)
>       at Location.set href [as href] (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Location.js:121:37)
>       at /Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/src/redux/actions/userActions.js:65:3
>       at Object.dispatch (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/node_modules/redux-thunk/lib/index.js:11:18)
>       at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jun1/Projects/web-client/src/redux/actions/__test__/userActions.test.js:146:17) undefined
>
>   at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
>   at module.exports (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:12:26)
>   at navigateFetch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/navigation.js:76:3)
>   at exports.navigate (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/navigation.js:54:3)
>   at LocationImpl._locationObjectNavigate (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/Location-impl.js:31:5)
>   at LocationImpl._locationObjectSetterNavigate (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/Location-impl.js:25:17)
>   at LocationImpl.set href [as href] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/Location-impl.js:47:10)
> ```

My unit test looks like this:

```
describe("User sign out", () => {
  it("should sign user out", async (done) => {
    await store.dispatch(signout());

    const actions = store.getActions();
    expect(actions.length).toBe(1);
    expect(actions[0]).toMatchObject({ type: USER_SIGNOUT });

    expect(localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    expect(document.location.href).toEqual("/signin");
    done();
  });
```

How can I get my test to pass and make the assertion `expect(document.location.href).toEqual("/signin");` to pass and also make sure the above exception is not thrown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock window.location.href with Jest + Vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021037/how-to-mock-window-location-href-with-jest-vuejs)

Comment: I've tried that and a few other ones like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954101/jest-error-when-set-or-assign-window-location` and `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090231/how-to-fix-error-not-implemented-navigation-except-hash-changes` with no luck