# Fetch dynamic global variables in JEST

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a Javascript application.

I am writing tests for it in JEST.

I have to access the global variables set in some of the JS files into the unit tests.

I have searched on the google for quite a few hours, but couldn't find any leads.

It would be very helpful, if you share some information about it.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object

Comment: @DanielLizik this is just for static values. I also need the values then they are changed in the application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-to-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest

Comment: I have a variable name $app in index.js. It is constantly updated throughout the application. I need to get the updated value of the variable in my test file.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, reproducible code ?