# How to mock the JavaScript window.open and window.close?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

PFB snapshot of my code.

```
const childWindow = window.open('https://example.com')
setTimeout(() => {
    childWindow.close()
}, 1000)
```

I am not able to write a unit test case for the above snapshot.

Can anyone please give me some ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock the JavaScript window object using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-can-i-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest)

Answer (score 11):

You can directly mock the window.open using `jest.fn()`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-to-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest) has more examples, have a look at it!!

```
jest.useFakeTimers() // Keep at the Top of the file

it('should test window.open', () => {
   const closeSpy = jest.fn()
   window.open = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ close: closeSpy })
   window.close = jest.fn()

   // Invoke main function

   expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled()
   expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://example.com')

   jest.runAllTimers()

   expect(closeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: Don't we need to reset it to the original value so that other test files don't use the mocked version unless they explicitly want to?

Comment: you can, using `jest.resetAllMocks()` in afterEach or afterAll