# How to mock window.navigator.language in jest 27

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, navigator, ts-jest

I've got a function like

```
export function formatDate(date: string){
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).format(new Date(date))
}
```

I'm attempting to write a unit test in vanilla jest (not using jsdom library), but as you can see I need to be able to mock `window.navigator.language`.

I've so far tried,

```
test('UK date format', () => {
  Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'language', {value: 'en-GB', configurable: true})
  expect(window.navigator.language).toBe('en-GB')
})
```

but I cannot for the life of my understand how you're supposed to mock window.navigator in jest.

Ideally I'd like to be able to mock a new value for window.navigator.language on each test. So I could have a test for `en-US`, `fr` etc etc

Any help to understand how you're supposed to mock this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888736/360674

Comment: Using global instead of window? Nope doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Did my answer help @ChrisB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can mock `window.navigator.language` using Jest as follows:

```
let windowSpy: jest.SpyInstance;;

beforeEach(() => {
    // Spy on the read-only window function which
    // returns a reference to the current window.
    windowSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'window', 'get');
});

// Clean-up the spy after every test
afterEach(() => windowSpy.mockRestore());

const setMockLanguage = (language: string) =>
    // Set how you want window.navigator.language to behave
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
        navigator: {
            language
        }
    }));

test('UK date format', () => {
    setMockLanguage('en-GB');

    expect(window.navigator.language).toBe('en-GB');
});

test('US date format', () => {
    setMockLanguage('en-US');

    expect(window.navigator.language).toBe('en-US');
});
```

I've included some comments in the code to help.

You can see it working [here](https://replit.com/@8enSmith/Mock-windownavigatorlanguage?v=1).

Comment: @ChrisB great news :)

Comment: How do you do this in TypeScript?

Comment: @Hyfy `windowSpy: jest.SpyInstance` should be enough

Comment: I've updated the code with the type as suggested by @nkint

Comment: not working 
"Property window does not have access type get"

Comment: @MaximeKrier you can see it working here https://replit.com/@8enSmith/Mock-windownavigatorlanguage?v=1