# React/Jest use either mock window value or resolve error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

My app uses the window object to inject environmental variables at runtime for docker, however my tests are coming back with the error below:

url config:

```
declare const window: Window &
    typeof globalThis & {
        _env_: any
    }

export const url = window._env_.REACT_APP_API_URL;
export const baseUrl = url;
```

error in tests as the handlers use the baseUrl, but even if I change the handlers to hardcoded values the below error comes:

● Test suite failed to run
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'REACT_APP_API_URL')

```
      4 |     }
      5 |
    > 6 | export const url = window._env_.REACT_APP_API_URL;
        |                                 ^
      7 | export const baseUrl = url;
```

setupTests.tsx

```
// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { setLogger } from 'react-query'
import { server } from './mocks/server'

declare const window: Window &
typeof globalThis & {
    _env_: any
}

window._env_.REACT_APP_API_URL = "https://wwww.xxxxx.com"

beforeAll(() => server.listen())
// Reset any request handlers that we may add during the tests,
// so they don't affect other tests.

afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())

// Clean up after the tests are finished.
afterAll(() => server.close())

// silence react-query errors
setLogger({
    log: console.log,
    warn: console.warn,
    error: () => {},
})
```

Any idea's? So where ever there is an api call I get this error in the tests for jest/React.

Comment: Hey there, I don't believe window gets mocked when running Jest tests. You might have to set your env variable in another way. See if this helps! https://dev.to/darkmavis1980/how-to-mock-environmental-variables-with-jest-2j3c

Comment: hmmm, any other suggestions?

Comment: The test runner clearly states, that `_env_` is `undefined`, so probably you didn't set up it properly for tests. Are you sure you augment window object not only for browser build, but for test's node env too?

Comment: I'm not sure where I would need to do that? @Temoncher

Comment: I have updated my question with setup tests

Comment: I tried adding in the setUp tests as above but still get the same error.

Comment: It seems to me that your `setupTests` should work as expected. Did you try to set `window._env_` inside the actual test right before the api call? Does it behave the same way?

Comment: Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/41885841/13104050

Comment: Not sure if setupTests is setup correctly for this scenario, totally confused

Answer (score 0):

you can mock the global `window` var

`test/setup.js`

```
window.env. REACT_APP_API_URL = 'something';
```

then you need to add in `package.json` file

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./test/setup.js"
    ],
```

OR

you can define global var in CLI like this

```
npm run jest -- --globals='{"window": "someUrl", "value": "someValue"}'
```

Comment: Would npm run jest be the same as npm run test ?

Comment: Also can't override create-react-app with the jest object?

Comment: How would this be for a create-react-app setup?

Comment: @Sole
I think it's possible

Comment: can you elaborate?