# Jest: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: window

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When I run jest tests locally with `yarn test:unit:watch`, I am getting this error from the jest library:

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot redefine property: window

at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-canvas-mock/lib/index.js:11:17)
```

Any suggestion what's wrong? I tried to delete node_modules and reinstall and also to clone the repo again but it's repeating. Others are not facing this problem.

Comment: I got such an error in our own testing codebase, and was able to fix it by creating a mock implementation following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999581

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to `mockImplementation` approach mentioned by @marcw ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999581/3211932)) and since I used `Object.create` approach from the same thread ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57612249/3211932)), I was able to solve the issue by changing

```js
global.window = Object.create(window);
```

to

```js
global.window ??= Object.create(window);
```

Answer (score 9):

This was an [issue in jest-canvas-mock](https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock/issues/89) that was fixed in 2.4.0.

Upgrading to 2.4.0 or later should resolve the issue, and allow use of node 18 or better.

Comment: I can not confirm this. Got 2.4.0 and it is still an issue.

Comment: I added `npm install jest-canvas-mock@latest --legacy-peer-deps` to my CI pipeline and that did fix it.