# Mock Notification Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, notifications, jestjs

I have this code:

```
const browserNotification = new Notification(title, options);

browserNotification.onshow = () => this.props.sendTracking('in-app-chat-notification-start');

browserNotification.onclick = event => {
  const notification = event.target;

  this.props.router.push(notification.data.url.split('.com')[1]);
  this.props.sendTracking('in-app-chat-notification-complete');

  notification.close();
};
```

I'm trying to mock window Notification because I need to call these two methods (*onshow* and *onclick*):

```
it('should call onshow method', () => {
  window.Notification = () => ({
    onshow: jest.fn(),
    onclick: jest.fn()
  });
  const instance = shallow(<MyComponent />).instance();

  instance.myMethod();

  //window.Notification.onShow();

  expect(sendTracking).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

I know that if I do that, I'm losing the original method but, since tests does not have window and Notification, I have to mock it.

How can do it properly with Jest in order to pass this code?

I have tried also mocking with [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest), but at the end, is the same as window.

The coverage:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking globals in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest)

Comment: Hi, I have checked that and does not help me. As you can see, I'm doing exactly the same but without global (I'm using window). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I think it will be the same, just replace window by global in your case and it should work

Comment: Let me check again then.

Comment: The same, my problem is that I want to fire those methods (onclick and onshow) in my tests.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, it's not onshow and onclick that should be mocked, it's sent tracking. You need to either have a reference to browserNotification and then call it's onshow method to see if it's working. Do you have access to that object from your component? Otherwise, modify the mock Notification class so that it will expose the object its creation

Comment: browserNotification is created few lines before as this:
`const browserNotification = new Notification(title, options);`
so at the end is created from global.Notification. What I mean is that I can't call it from anywhere until I don't mock Notification.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Could you try it using `Object.defineProperty(globalObject, key, { value, writable: true });`

Comment: I tried this code in my test but it doesn't work. Have in mind that inside tests, we don't have window or global so, it will never works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I suceded to test those two methods by splitting the code that I showed in my question.

This is it:

```
handleNewFirebaseNotification = notification => {
  const title = notification.data.title || 'letgo';
  const options = {
    body: notification.data.body,
    icon: notification.data.icon || 'https://static.letgo.com/site-images/logo_letgo_share_fb.jpg',
    data: {
      url: notification.data.url
    }
  };

  this.handleNotifications(title, options);
};

handleNotifications = (title, options) => {
  const browserNotification = new Notification(title, options);

  browserNotification.onshow = this.onShowNotification;
  browserNotification.onClick = this.onClickNotification;
}

onShowNotification = () => {
  this.props.sendTracking('in-app-chat-notification-start')
}

onClickNotification = event => {
  const notification = event.target;

  this.props.router.push(notification.data.url.split('.com')[1]);
  this.props.sendTracking('in-app-chat-notification-complete');

  notification.close();
}
```

And then I can test with enzyme all this new methods. For example:

```
it('should call handleNewFirebaseNotification and then call handleNotifications with title and icon', () => {
  window.Notification = () => ({
    onshow: jest.fn(),
    onclick: jest.fn()
  });
  const instance = shallow(mockComponent()).instance();
  const notificationMock = {
    data: {
      title: 'test',
      body: 'test',
      icon: 'test',
      url: 'test'
    }
  };

  instance.handleNewFirebaseNotification(notificationMock);

  expect(window.Notification()).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({
    onshow: expect.any(Function),
    onclick: expect.any(Function)
  }));
});
```

And one of the new methods:

```
it('should call onShowNotification', () => {
  const instance = shallow(mockComponent()).instance();

  instance.onShowNotification();

  expect(sendTrackingSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: This is not true because I'm using the arrow function and therefore ```this.props```is not undefined. Please, don't downvote or at least, try this before commenting