# Jest mock global variable's method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

In my application I have a global variable in an external file

```
const Translate = {
  trans: () => {... some code}
}
```

and I use it in my React component

```
const title = Translate.trans('title');
```

and in my Component.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Component from '../Component';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Component Snapshot Tests', () => {
  it('renders default Component correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});

afterEach(() => {
  global.Translator.trans = jest.fn(() => 'test text');
});
```

I get an error:

> "TypeError: Translator.trans is not a function"

Jest settings

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "globals": {
      "Translator": true
    }
  }
```

How better mock global variables in jest? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking globals in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest)

Comment: Does this work? `global.Translator = {
   trans: jest.fn(() => 'test text')
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, there is no need to set jest config.

`index.ts`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Translate';

interface ISomeComponentProps {
  title: string;
}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<ISomeComponentProps> {
  public render() {
    const title = (global as any).Translator.trans(this.props.title);
    return <div>title: {title}</div>;
  }
}

export { SomeComponent };
```

`Translate.ts`:

```
const Translator = {
  trans: text => text
};

(global as any).Translator = Translator;

export { Translator };
```

Unit test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { SomeComponent } from './';

(global as any).Translator.trans = jest.fn();

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  it('t1', () => {
    const mockTitle = 'test title';
    (global as any).Translator.trans.mockReturnValueOnce(mockTitle);
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent title={mockTitle} />);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe(`title: ${mockTitle}`);
    expect((global as any).Translator.trans).toBeCalledWith(mockTitle);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/47412169/index.spec.tsx
  SomeComponent
    ✓ t1 (14ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |    92.31 |      100 |    66.67 |    91.67 |                   |
 Translate.ts |       75 |      100 |        0 |       75 |                 2 |
 index.tsx    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.799s, estimated 6s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/47412169

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that you can mock variables/function globally for Jest:

`mockTranslate.js`

```
// Globally mock gettext
global.gettext = jest.fn((text) => text);
global.pgettext = jest.fn((context, text) => text);
```

And then in your `jest.config.js` include it in the `setupFiles`:

```
const config = {
 // other configs
};


// HERE
config.setupFiles = ['./mockTranslate.js'];

module.exports = config;
```