# mocking and forcing Window object to be empty

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am working on a react-native-web application,
the application has a logic something like this

```
return typeof Window !== 'undefined' ? ComponentA : ComponentB
```

now I am writing the test case for it,
I am trying to mock the global.Window
I need to mock it to be undefined once and have the Window once.

```
const originalWindow = {...global.Window};
  it('Should not have Window', () => {
    global.Window = undefined;
    console.log('global.Window: ', global.Window);

  });
  it('Should have window', () => {
     global.window = originalWindow
    console.log('window is present: ', Search);
  });
```

but in the second testCase the window is still undefined,
what is the way around?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425746/jest-js-force-window-to-be-undefined

Comment: The mentioned thread removes the window for the whole testFile, I need to modify the window for Each testCase