# Making the window to a different data type in the React testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a reusable hook for checking the window resize has been triggered or not.

I was using [Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme) for my unit testing, since I was not able to find the documentation and support for hooks I am using.

1. @testing-library/react
2. @testing-library/react-hooks

#### File *hooks.js*

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useWindowSize() {
    const isClient = typeof window === "object";

    function getSize() {
        return {
            width: isClient ? window.innerWidth : undefined,
            height: isClient ? window.innerHeight : undefined,
        };
    }

    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isClient) {
            return false;
        }

        function handleResize() {
            setWindowSize(getSize());
        }

        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount

    return windowSize;
}

export default {useWindowSize}
```

I was able to test the normal flow, but how can I make the window to a different data type, so I can make the code coverage of 100%?

#### File *hooks.test.js*

```
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import hooks from "..";

const { useWindowSize } = hooks;

describe("hooks", () => {
    it("should return a new size of window", () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useWindowSize());
        expect(result.current.width).toBe(1024);
        expect(result.current.height).toBe(768);

        act(() => {
            // Change the viewport to 500 pixels.
            window.innerWidth = 500;
            window.innerHeight = 500;
            // trigger the window resize event
            fireEvent(window, new Event("resize"));
        });

        expect(result.current.width).toBe(500);
        expect(result.current.height).toBe(500);
    });
    
    // How can I test if window is not an typeof object?
    it("should exit if its not window", () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useWindowSize());
        act(() => {
            // Change the window from object 
            window = "";
            fireEvent(window, new Event("resize"));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `window` is only available in the browser. When testing you need to mock it e.g. using [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). Enzyme has an example using JSDOM [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md) but the idea should work without enzyme as well

Comment: then why this is failing ?

Comment: Because `window` is always undefined

Comment: okay then how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Copy the setup.js code in https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md and then import it in the test file.

Comment: getting this error,     TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'. i added the code in a file called setup.js and i tried importing like const jsdom = require('./setup'), and without any import both time same error now its failing for both test cases

Comment: @apokryfos tried it , but didnt worked any idea on this ?

Comment: Did you require setup before requiring react, as it says in the link provided by @apokryfos?