# how to mock globals window object in jest in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

anyone know how I can mock window object for testing the value of `feature` ? Following is my concept code, I want to test if expEnabled is enable feature is  'exp is enabled'
otherwise feature is  'exp is disable'
I have tried to [mocking global.window in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691604/mocking-global-window-in-jest)
and [Mocking globals in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest) but it does not seem work for me.

**Updated:**
after moving the code `const expEnabled = typeof window !== 'undefined' && !!window?.app?.initialAppProps?.exp?.my_feature;` into function it seems like use `Object.defineProperty` works.

```
//source code
import Koa from 'koa';
export interface InitialAppProps {
  exp: Koa.DefaultState['exp'];

}
const expEnabled = typeof window !== 'undefined' && !!window?.app?.initialAppProps?.exp?.my_feature;

export function testMock(){
  return typeof window !== 'undefined' && !!window?.app?.initialAppProps?.exp?.my_feature;
}

//app is Functional component of my app from react
export const feature = [expEnabled  ? 'exp is enabled' : 'exp is disable']
export const featureNew = [testMock()  ? 'exp is enabled' : 'exp is disable']



//test code
describe('expEnabled', () => {
  it('feature should be enabled if expEnabled is trued', () => {
/*
    how can I mock expEnabled is true?
    I have tried this and console.log before expect. the right value print out but I still fail on expect
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'window', {
       value: {
         app: {initialAppProps: {exp: {my_feature: true}}},
       },
       writable: true,
     });
*/
    expect(feature).toEqual('exp is enabled');
  });
  it('feature should be enabled if expEnabled is trued', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'window', {
       value: {
         app: {initialAppProps: {exp: {my_feature: true}}},
       },
       writable: true,
     });
     expect(featureNew).toEqual('exp is enabled');
  })
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock the JavaScript 'window' object using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-can-i-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest)

Answer (score 2):

Just assign a value to `window.app.initialAppProps.exp.my_feature`. You need to reset the module before executing each test case since the `./index` module will be cached in the `require.cache` object. This means the value of `expEnabled` variable will be cached too.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    app: {
      initialAppProps: {
        exp: {
          my_feature: boolean;
        };
      };
    };
  }
}

const expEnabled = typeof window !== 'undefined' && !!window.app.initialAppProps.exp.my_feature;
export const feature = [expEnabled ? 'exp is enabled' : 'exp is disable'];
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
describe('67041178', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    window.app = {
      initialAppProps: {
        exp: { my_feature: false },
      },
    };
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('should enable', () => {
    window.app.initialAppProps.exp.my_feature = true;
    const { feature } = require('./');
    expect(feature).toEqual(['exp is enabled']);
  });

  it('should disable', () => {
    window.app.initialAppProps.exp.my_feature = false;
    const { feature } = require('./');
    expect(feature).toEqual(['exp is disable']);
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'window', {
      value: {
        app: { initialAppProps: { exp: { my_feature: true } } },
      },
      writable: true,
    });
    const { feature } = require('./');
    expect(feature).toEqual(['exp is enabled']);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67041178/index.test.ts (13.133 s)
  67041178
    ✓ should enable (8 ms)
    ✓ should disable (1 ms)
    ✓ should pass (1 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.167 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/67041178

Comment: obvious I cannt change anything from index.ts. but I just update my question with using `Object.defineProperty....` and not working.

Comment: @jacobcan118 Updated answer. `Object.defineProperty()` works for me. You can check the source code

Comment: hm....it does not work for me. i change here to debug `export const feature = [expEnabled];`. i can see feature is always `[false]`

Comment: after continually trying...i found out that the problem maybe  like I cannt mock the const `expEnabled` for some reason. if I move the `expEnabled` into function. it seems work. I will update my question