# How can I mock the google-apps-script interfaces, such as Logger/DataStudio, in my jest tests?

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm trying to test our `DataStudio` code (in Typescript), which uses certain Interfaces from the google-apps-script libraries, e.g. the `Logger` and `DataStudio` Interfaces. These reside in `.d.ts` files, so I can't easily import them. This is how `Logger` is defined in the `google-apps-script.base.d.ts` file:

```
/// <reference path="google-apps-script.types.d.ts" />

declare namespace GoogleAppsScript {
  export module Base {
  [...]
    export interface Logger {
      clear(): void;
      getLog(): string;
      log(data: Object): Logger;
      log(format: string, ...values: Object[]): Logger;
    }
  }
}
declare var Logger: GoogleAppsScript.Base.Logger;
```

I'm running jest tests on functions which use these interfaces, but I'm receiving e.g. `Logger is not defined`, so I need to somehow mock these Interfaces.

Does anyone know how I can import these interfaces so I can mock them? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

See [Mocking globals in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest). For example, to mock out the console, you could have the following at the top of your test file:

```
global.Logger = jest.fn(console.log)
```