# Mocking the navigator object

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In my app I use the `navigator` object to store a string in the clipboard:

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText('string')
```

But when I write my test in Jest and mock this object I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'writeText' of undefined

This is how I mock `navigator` in my test file:

```js
//  Mock clipboard object
const clipboardWriteTextSpy = jest.fn()
navigator = {
  clipboard: {
    writeText: clipboardWriteTextSpy
  }
}
```

---

**Update**

I also tried using `global.navigator` but I still have the error:

```js
global.navigator = {
  clipboard: {
    writeText: clipboardWriteTextSpy
  }
}
```

Has someone an idea how to mock this object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking globals in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to mock non-application logic (like browser's `navigator`) is to write a function as part of your application and mock it. Example:

```
// clipboard.js

export const setClipboard = (text) => navigator.clipboard.writeText('string');
```

Then mock it in your test:

```
// some.test.js

import { setClipboard } from './clipboard';

jest.mock('./clipboard');
```

Comment: Yes would be great but I need for that to change the source code.

Comment: Then refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest