# How to write unit test cases for responsiveness using react testing library & jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to set `window.screen.width`. According to that, I want to test some features, but `window.screen.width` is a read-only property so it can't be changed.

Are there any options in jest to write test cases for responsiveness scenarios?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking globals in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest)